# How to remove unknown character from a filename in Linux

Tags: linux, filenames, special-characters

I am using Nextcloud to sync files from computer A (unknown computer - i'm guessing Mac) to computer B (Rocky Linux server).

Some of the invoices that come from computer A have special characters in their name, this causes weird behaviour on the Rocky Linux server

[image: weird symbol on Rocky Linux]

Does anyone have experience with this kind of behaviour? Preferably, I would like to check the filename first for unknown characters, and then strip the unknown character from the filename

EDIT:

Original file name:

```
FACTUUR n°/Credit Nota n° -0097000156
```

It seems it also has a forward slash in it, but this is magically removed after I download the file

I now changed my locale to

```
localectl set-locale en_US.UTF-8
```

This is the output of localectl

[image: localectl output]

And this is the output of locale

[image: locale output]

Now the files look like this on the server:

[image]

"Weird behaviour" explained:

I also host an application on this server which opens the file in particular in the asp.net core application, it cannot "find" the file to open due to the symbol in the name i suppose

[image: wierd behaviour explained]

EDIT:

Previous output locale was the same, except for the LANG section, that was

```
LANG=en_US
```

Output from the

```
echo FACTUUR*-0097000156.PDF|od -tx1 -c
```

command:

```
0000000  46  41  43  54  55  55  52  20  6e  b0  43  72  65  64  69  74
          F   A   C   T   U   U   R       n 260   C   r   e   d   i   t
0000020  20  4e  6f  74  61  20  20  6e  b0  20  2d  30  30  39  30  30
              N   o   t   a           n 260       -   0   0   9   0   0
0000040  30  36  33  32  34  2e  50  44  46  0a
          0   6   3   2   4   .   P   D   F  \n
0000052
```

I would like to allow all special characters that are supported in a regular AZERTY / QWERTY keyboard

There also is a posibility to upload the file trough the application itself, in this case, the file is uploaded perfectly

[image: uploaded file perfectly]
[image: uploaded file perfectly on CLI]

Kind regards

Comment: What kind of "weird behaviour" do you see? Only strange characters in e.g. `ls` output? Or something serious? Computer A seems to use a different character encoding than computer B. Can you define a set of allowed characters and remove everything else? If computer A uses a multi-byte encoding and computer B a single-byte encoding you might see wrong characters that are part of the set of valid characters. Show the output of the `locale` command on both computers. Or for older Mac OS versions, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/661935/10622916

Comment: @Bodo Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question, I have no access to the macOS machine, I think its due to the settings on my Rocky Linux server? I think the problem is causued by the Rocky Linux instance unable to handle the symbol?

Comment: What was your original locale? How did you get the original file name? Show the exact error(s) you get from the asp.net core application? Maybe you have to set the locale for this application, too. Show the output of `echo FACTUUR*-0097000156.PDF|od -tx1 -c` [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste the command and its output *as text*. Add details how you want to modify the file names. You did not answer my question "*Can you define a set of allowed characters and remove everything else?*"

Comment: @Bodo I have updated my question, my bad about the guidelines, I have now pasted the result as text

Comment: The requirement "all special characters that are supported in a regular AZERTY / QWERTY keyboard" is probably impossible to fulfill. "AZERTY" and "QUERTY" are not sufficient to define which special characters are available on the keyboard (see Wikipedia), and at least some of these variants contain characters that have different values depending on the encoding, e.g. the degree character `°`. Without knowing which encoding is used by the wrong file names, you can only use printable ASCII characters and remove everything else.